# why does this make an infinite loop?

Tags: c

```
    if (num_samples2 == 252) {
        char buffer[1024];
        char* p = buffer;
        for(int a = 1; a < num_samples2 - 6; a = a + 6){
            p += sprintf(p, "%f,",data_samples[a]);
            p += sprintf(p, "%f,",data_samples[a+1]);
            p += sprintf(p, "%f,",data_samples[a+2]);
            p += sprintf(p, "%f,",data_samples[a+3]);
            p += sprintf(p, "%f,",data_samples[a+4]);
            p += sprintf(p, "%f",data_samples[a+5]);
        }
    }
```

What is the reason to an infinite loop, and I dont really understand why=?

Comment: You probably go out of bounds of the array `buffer`.

Comment: where is the definition of the array data_samples? Or do you mean the array buffer?

Comment: You only have space in `buffer` for three characters per float. Accessing outside it is undefined.

Comment: Compile with `-fsanitize=address` and/or/run with valgrind or use a debugger...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala valgrind will not help on the stack. The sanitizer is a good idea.

Comment: Add `if (p - buffer >= 1024) {printf("buffer overflow"); exit(1);}` at the start of the `for` loop and you'll understand

Comment: So the buffer is too small? How to calculate the necessary size?

Comment: @JohnDign you probably can't calculate the required size, see Steve Summit's answer below.

Comment: @MichaelWalz the size can be calculated using `fprintf` on `/dev/null` or `snprintf` on `NULL` with `0` as the size. There is some concern about `snprintf`'s implementation on windows though.

Comment: Why do you have a loop with a body that is the same line repeated 6 times? Can't you do the same thing with a single line and increment your counter by 1 instead of 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: your buffer is not big enough.

It looks like you're converting approximately 252 floating-point values to string format, and concatenating them together into `buffer`.  Suppose the values are something line `123.456789`.  That's 10 characters for one value, and 10 × 252 = 2520, which is over twice as big as `buffer`. (And that's not counting the commas, either.)

Why does this lead to an infinite loop?  Well, when you overflow a buffer -- that is, when you write more to it than it's allocated to hold, meaning that you "run off the end", what happens is that you start scribbling over some other part of memory.  In this case, it's quite likely that you're writing string-formatted floating-point numbers on top of the memory that's used to hold the `i` and/or `num_samples` variables.  Perhaps `i` is getting changed to -1000000000, meaning that it can never get back up to `num_samples`.  Or perhaps `num_samples` is getting changed to 1000000000, meaning that `i` can never get up to it.  Or perhaps something even worse than that is happening.

The quick fix would be to make `buffer` bigger, perhaps

```
char buffer[5000];
```

But this is still risky.  I don't know how big your floating-point values are, and you may not, either.  So it's hard (if not impossible) to pick a size for `buffer` that guarantees that it won't overflow.  But, as you may know, buffer overflow is a huge problem.  You really do want to eliminate the possibility.  Here, you have two choices: (1) arrange some way to dynamically allocate the array so that it's guaranteed to be big enough (growing it as you go, if necessary) or (2) check if the buffer overflows, and complain if it does.

I'll try to demonstrate both techniques, but it will take a while.

First, we have to decide how big our floating-point values might be when printed out as strings, and even this can be tricky.  It's easy to control how many digits are printed to the right of the decimal point; we can specify this by using, for example, `%.3f` to print three places past the decimal.  But controlling the number of digits to the left of the decimal is tricker -- in fact there's not a good way to do this.  You might think that something like `%8.3f` would work.  This requests 3 places past the decimal, and an overall size of 8.  But the 8 is a *minimum*.  If your value is shorter than 8 characters, it'll get padded out with spaces until it's exactly 8 characters.  (You might use this to get some columns to line up, or something.)  But if the resulting value is *longer* than 8 characters -- for example, if you had the value 100000.234 -- `sprintf` quietly overflows your field width and generates something longer than the 8 characters you asked for.  (It does *not* replace your number with a field overflow indication like `####.###`, as some languages do.)

So we're going to have to guess how big our numbers might be, but then use some other technique (outside of `sprintf`) to prevent overflow.

Method 2 -- merely detecting overflow -- is somewhat easier.  The method would be something like this:

```
char buffer[5000];
int buf_avail = 5000;
char *p = buffer;

int n = snprintf(p, buf_avail, "%.3f,", data_samples[a]);
p += n;
buf_avail -= n;
```

Here we use `snprintf` rather than `sprintf`, which is always a good idea.  `snprintf` lets us tell it how big our destination buffer is, so that `snprintf` can promise not to overflow it.  It's a little tricky because you're using multiple calls to build up the string, so you have to maintain an auxiliary variable, `buf_avail`, to keep track of how much space is left.  After each call to `snprintf`, `buf_avail` is decremented by however many characters that call to `snprintf` added.

That's a start, but it's actually not quite good enough.

[Breaking news: it's especially not good enough because I just remembered that `snprintf` does *not* return the number of characters it wrote, but rather, the number of characters it *would have* written, if the buffer was big enough.  That ends up being taken care of by the improvements below, but I don't have tome to rewrite this whole answer just now.]

The first question is, what if `snprintf` returns a negative number, to indicate some kind of error condition?  This first, simple code fragment doesn't check for that possibility, so it will end up making `buf_avail` bigger again, which would be an error.

I don't think `snprintf` is supposed to return negative values, but it's worth at least thinking about the possibility.  If you check the documentation, you'll probably find that it doesn't -- but then again, I have this memory that there was a common implementation -- perhaps under Windows -- that *did* return -1 under some condition.  So, to be on the safe side, it's probably a good idea to check for it:

```
n = snprintf(p, buf_avail, "%.3f,", data_samples[a]);
if(n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "snprintf failure\n");
    ... exit or return or break ...
}
p += n;
buf_avail -= n;
```

And then the other problem is that, if we do overflow the buffer, we won't notice.  As long as we accurately maintain the `buf_avail` value, and keep handing the updated value to `snprintf`, `snprintf` won't write too much, but eventually it'll start writing nothing (because there's no room), and returning 0.  So we should probably check for that condition, too.  Actually what we care about is not so much `snprintf` returning 0, but returning less than it should have, indicating that it hit the end of the buffer.  But of course for any given call we don't know how many characters it "should" return (the fact that we don't know that is one of the things making this problem tricky).  Instead, we can do a pretty good job of detecting that the buffer wasn't big enough by watching for `buf_avail` going to 0:

```
n = snprintf(p, buf_avail, "%.3f,", data_samples[a]);
if(n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "snprintf failure\n");
    ... exit or return or break ...
}
p += n;
buf_avail -= n;
if(buf_avail <= 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "buffer full\n");
    ... exit or return or break ...
}
```

(And this *still* isn't perfect; it will end up printing `"buffer full"` in the -- hopefully rare -- case that `buffer` was *exactly* big enough for the 252 floating-point values, with no room to spare.  So we should make `buffer` comfortably bigger than we think it needs to be.)

So that's method 2 -- and remember, that was the "easy" one!

Method 1 involves *dynamic memory allocation* (and reallocation).  This might be considered an intermediate- (or even advanced) level technique, but it's an important and common one in C, so it's worth learning about sooner or later.

We're going to use `malloc` to make an initial allocation of a `buffer` which we think ought to be big enough.
We're going to format the floating-point numbers, one at a time, into a second, temporary buffer.  (And there's then the question of how to know how big to make *that* buffer.)
If there's room in the main buffer, we're going to simply append the temporary buffer to the main buffer.  But if there's not room, we're going to use the indispensible `realloc` function to make the main buffer bigger, so there *is* room.

So here's the code.  First, there's a different set of variables we're going to need:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
int buf_alloc = 0;
int buf_used = 0;
char tmpbuf[50];
```

Then, we make our initial guess for how big the overall buffer needs to be, and allocate it with `malloc`:

```
buf_alloc = 10;
buffer = malloc(buf_alloc);
if(buffer == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "malloc failure\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Normally, of course, we'd pick a considerably bigger initial value for `buf_alloc`.  My value of 10 is way too small; we're going to have to reallocate almost immediately.  But that's deliberate: I want to make sure I actually test my reallocation code!  (If I made the initial value of `buf_alloc` truly big enough right away, such that it never reallocated during any of my testing, and if the first actual reallocation occurred when the program was in front of a customer, and it didn't work, I'd be very sorry.)

Now, inside the loop, we can format each floating-point number into `tmpbuf`, see whether it will fit, and if not, reallocate `buffer`:

```
n = snprintf(tmpbuf, sizeof(tmpbuf), "%.3f,", data_samples[a]);
if(n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "snprintf failure\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(buf_used + n + 1 > buf_alloc) {
    buf_alloc = buf_used + n + 5;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, buf_alloc);
    if(buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "realloc failure\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

strcpy(buffer + buf_used, tmpbuf);
buf_used += n;
```

There are several things to notice here:

- It's less useful to maintain a `buf_avail` variable; instead here I'm keeping `buf_used`.
- We can't keep that `p` variable pointing at the next spot in `buffer` to copy something into, because every time we reallocate, the `buffer` might move somewhere else in memory, invalidating `p`.
- Once again I've used a too-small memory increment, `buf_used + n + 5`.  Normally you'd give yourself something like `buf_used + n + 50`, and in fact it's usually preferable to use a multiplicative rather than an additive growth sequence.

---

And then there's also method 3.  Do you *really* need to concatenate all these formatted floating-point values together into a single comma-separated string?  If the end goal is to write them out to a file, or a network connection, or something, it's often much more straightforward to write them to the file or stream directly (using `fprintf`, say), rather than constructing them first in an intermediate string buffer.  And of course that way you don't have to worry about making the intermediate string buffer big enough.

Comment: So if i say like %8f, so I know its not more than 8 characters?

Comment: @JohnDign No, turns out that's not good enough.  Stay tuned for an update.

Comment: another option is to do a dummy `fprintf` to `/dev/null` to just get the size of the required buffer and then allocate the appropriate size buffer.

Comment: Beware: The first code fragment in this answer turns out to be *wrong*, because `snprintf` doesn't always return the exact number of characters written.  For now the `buf_avail <= 0` test should, fortuitously, take care of this.  Proper fix later.  (Now why did I sign up for this answer, again?)

Answer (score 0):

This code has no infinite loop

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int num_samples2 = 252;
    for (int a = 1; a < num_samples2 - 6; a = a + 6) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }
}
```

It returns `1 7 13 19 25 31 37 43 49 55 61 67 73 79 85 91 97 103 109 115 121 127 133 139 145 151 157 163 169 175 181 187 193 199 205 211 217 223 229 235 241`

As others have pointed, you probably write into `buffer` beyond `1024` and than you have undefined behaviour.

Use the compile option `-fsanitize=address` to track this with clang or gcc.

Comment: BTW the question is tagged C, and not C++